# Solving a master equation with linear coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE:

$$
\partial_t P(x,y,t)=x\partial_xP(x,y,t)+(y-1)\partial_yP(x,y,t)+2P(x,y,t).
$$

`Mathematica` suggests that the solution is
$$
\dfrac{f((y-1)/x,t+\log x)}{x^2},
$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary function.

**My question is**: How to solve this equation? Or put it in other words, how can I arrive at the solution given by `Mathematica`?

Comment: The trouble is that if $P(\ ,\ ,0)$ is singular, every $P(\ ,\ ,t)$ is singular, and then one wonders what the PDE even means.

Comment: @Did,What will happen if we just ignore the initial conditions?

Comment: Because the PDE is "true only when $x$ is close to $0$ and $y$ is close to $1$", it's unclear how it informs the initial conditions where $(x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: @hardmath, for the moment, I don't worry about the initial conditions. I have edited the page and removed descriptions concerning initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_tP(x,y,t)=x\partial_xP(x,y,t)+(y-1)\partial_yP(x,y,t)+2P(x,y,t)$

$\partial_tP(x,y,t)-x\partial_xP(x,y,t)+(1-y)\partial_yP(x,y,t)=2P(x,y,t)$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-x$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=x_0e^{-s}=x_0e^{-t}$

$\dfrac{dy}{ds}=1-y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=(y_0-1)e^{-s}+1=(y_0-1)e^{-t}+1$

$\dfrac{dP}{ds}=2P$ , letting $P(0)=f(x_0,y_0)$ , we have $P(x,y,t)=f(x_0,y_0)e^{2s}=f(xe^t,(y-1)e^t+1)e^{2t}$